# What is the difference between <unistd.h> and <sys/unistd.h>?

Tags: c

Building my project on Alpine Linux (using the musl libc), I get an error from the compiler:

> <sys/unistd.h> not found

musl libc doesn't have a `<sys/unistd.h>`. I changed the include line to `#include <unistd.h>` and it compiles successfully (there is still features not working).

I'm curious about the difference between `<unistd.h>` and `<sys/unistd.h>`, but I can't find any answer on Google. There is a StackOverflow question about different `unistd.h`, but all of the answers don't even mention anything about `unistd.h`.

Comment: POSIX says “use `#include <unistd.h>`”.  Unless some particular (non-standard) interface is documented to require `sys/unistd.h`, do not use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `unistd.h` file is common on POSIX systems (Linux, UNIX, MacOS, etc.) and contains declarations of functions and macros used in on these systems.

`sys/unistd.h` is most likely a remnant from older systems.  On CentOS, this file simply contains `#include <unistd.h>`.  It does not exist on Alpine or Debian based systems.

Comment: On my OpenBSD machine:
On sys/unistd.h there is a line
@(#)unistd.h    8.2 (Berkeley) 1/7/94
but unistd.h: @(#)unistd.h    5.13 (Berkeley) 6/17/91
which means sys/unistd.h is created after unistd.h
The content of sys/unistd.h does not contain any syscall, just macros.

Comment: `unistd.h` is common on POSIX systems because it is *specified* by POSIX.  `sys/unistd.h` is not.  I could easily believe that the latter is a BSD-ism that was not adopted by POSIX.  The fact that the two files have the same basename should not be taken as significant -- they must be understood as logically different headers.  One should include the headers that the documentation of each function you want to call designates, in exactly the form those docs specify.